# How to use relationship data outside of relationship field in Laravel Nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-6

I am trying to figure out how to do something seemingly simple with Laravel Nova, but I can't figure this out.

What I want to do is reference relationship data in a text field. I see in Nova, and understand how to reference a relationship via the `HasOne, HasMany ...` facades. But what I want to do is get relationship data like this:

```
Text::make('State', $this->state->name)
```

This doesn't work, and something I noticed when trying to debug is that each function in a Nova resource seems to run multiple times. Here is the logging I added:

```
public function fields(Request $request) {
    logger($this->state->name)
}
```

When I do this, there are 3 logging instances, the first 2 containing the state name, and the third not. I think that may have something to do with it not working, but don't know what might be causing this.

Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a simple way to get relationship data into a Nova `Text` field, just use a closure:

`Text::make('State', function() { 
    return $this->state->name;
})`

As for the multiple calls to the `fields` function, the answer has to do with the question: *Do you have another `Resource` in your Nova folder that is related to the `Resource` we are discussing?* If so, that is why -- it needs to call `fields` to display it properly. You can examine the following query string parameters to get more insight: `viaResource`, `viaResourceId`, and `viaRelationship`.

Comment: Thank you @udog - that is the answer I was looking for!!

Comment: @udog thank your answer was useful to me too. Simply because `viaResource`, `viaResourceId`, and `viaRelationship` isn't properly documented on the Nova documentation, and only briefly mentioned under actions. There are a multituyde of uses for them but it's a bit hard to follow without any real documentation.